# powershell regular expressions

Tags: regex, powershell

quick one:

```
$logFile="D:\Code\functest\1725.log"
function getTime($pattern) {
  Get-Content $logFile | %{ if ($_.Split('\t') -match $pattern) {$_} }
}
getTime("code")
```

gives me

```
simple  17-Feb-2011 10:45:27    Updating source code to revision: 49285
simple  17-Feb-2011 10:54:22    Updated source code to revision: 49285
```

but if I change the print value from

```
$_
```

to

```
$matches
```

I get nothing. I thought this array should have been created automatically? probably something silly, but this is my first day of using powershell :-)

**EDIT:** what I want to return is

```
Get-Date (column 2 of the matching line)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your call to `Split()` is using C# conventions to escape the `t` to specify a tab character.  In PowerShell, you use a single backtick e.g. `` $_.Split("`t") ``.  Also `-match` is behaving a bit differently on an array like this so have it operate on each individual string like so:

```
Get-Content $logFile | Foreach {$_.Split("`t")} | Where { $_ -match $pattern }
```

There's also a sort of hidden trick here with Get-Content where you can get it to split for you:

```
Get-Content $logFile -del "`t" | Where { $_ -match $pattern }
```

Update: based on the updated question, try something like this:

```
gc $logFile | % {$cols = $_.Split("`t"); if ($cols[2] -match $pattern) {$cols[1]}}
```

Keeping in mind that arrays are 0-based in PowerShell.  If the text is already in a DateTime format that PowerShell/.NET understand, you can just cast it to a DateTime like so `[DateTime]$cols[1]`.

Comment: thanks for the reply! the problem is, my question was probably wrong :-) I have lines consisting of 3 columns, the $pattern matches the third column, but I want to return Get-Date of the second column of that line. How should I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The `$_.Split('\t')` is breaking it.
First, it's breaking on every letter "t", not at tabs. 
Second, it return a array that confounds `-match`.

With the following code:

```
Get-Content $logFile | %{ if ($_ -match $pattern) { $matches } }
```

`getTime("code")` would return:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                       
----                           -----                                                                                                                                       
0                              code                                                                                                                                        
0                              code
```

This would allow to search with regular expressions, as in

```
$answerArray = getTime("(\t)(\d+)")
$digitsOfSecondResult = $answerArray[1][2]
Write-Output $digitsOfSecondResult
```

If you just want to print the lines that match the pattern, try:

```
Get-Content $logFile | %{ if ($_ -match $pattern) { $_} }
```

To get the date:

```
function getTime($pattern) {
  Get-Content $logFile | %{ if ($_ -match $pattern) { Get-Date $matches[1] } }
}
getTime("`t(.+)`t.*code")
```

Or:

```
function getTime($pattern) {
  Get-Content $logFile | %{ if ($_ -match "`t(.+)`t.*$pattern") { Get-Date $matches[1] } }
}
getTime("code")
```

Comment: @seminolas Get-Date $matches[1], if $pattern is "`t(.+)`t.*code", returns the date field of the lines the contain the word "code" in the third field. (`t means tab).